# Installing Numpy and matplotlib on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

So I've been trying to install matplotlib and numpy on my Mac OS X 10.8 for two days straight now. Just can't seem to get them up and running. I get all sorts of errors. I finally managed to install numpy 1.5 then when I install matplotlib with "pip install matplotlib==1.0.1", I get an error after some progress through the installation: This is the last part of the error:

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Isrc -Iagg24/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c CXX/IndirectPythonInterface.cxx -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/CXX/IndirectPythonInterface.o

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Isrc -Iagg24/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c CXX/cxxextensions.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/CXX/cxxextensions.o

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Isrc -Iagg24/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/backend_agg.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/src/backend_agg.o

In file included from src/backend_agg.cpp:9:

In file included from src/_backend_agg.h:32:

agg24/include/agg_renderer_outline_aa.h:1368:45: error: binding of reference to type 'agg::line_profile_aa' to a value of type 'const agg::line_profile_aa' drops qualifiers

        line_profile_aa& profile() { return *m_profile; }

                                            ^~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

When I type "gcc" in the terminal, it runs fine. I installed XCode 5 and the command line tools. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using a package manager, like [macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another (even simpler) option than Canopy and Anaconda, is just to download Spyder's [dmg](http://spyderlib.googlecode.com/files/spyder-2.2.5.dmg), which comes with the latest versions of Numpy, SciPy, matplotlib, Pandas, Sympy and the sci-kits. This is a pure drag and drop installer (like the Firefox or Chrome ones).

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the pain and simply install [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). It will install the full [SciPy stack](http://www.scipy.org/stackspec.html) (which includes NumPy and MatPlotLib) as well as many other useful packages (including [IPython](http://ipython.org), which is awesome!).

Happy coding :)

Comment: @askewchan Anaconda is good, but they [charge extra](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/mkl-optimizations/) for the MKL optimisations, which are [included](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/) in the free version of Canopy.